# Return value if criteria is not met in javascript .some() function

Tags: javascript, function

Given an array of numbers, I wish to use javascript's .some() method to find the first pair of mirror image numbers and return the pair.

e.g. [454,86,57,75,16,88]) should return [57,75]. If there are no numbers that mirror each other, I want to return [-1,-1]. I managed to get up to the point where if there are mirror image numbers, the numbers are returned. However, I can't get it to return [-1,-1]. Where did I go wrong?

```
var a=0
var b=0
arr=[13,15,19,32,49,61,73]

arr.some((x,i)=>{
    a=arr[i]
    b=arr[i+1]
    b= switchIt(b)
     if(a!==b){     //what if there are no mirror image numbers found?
       a = -1
       b = -1
    }else{
       return a==b
    }      
})

function switchIt(n){
    n= n.toString()
    n= n.split("")
    var [x,y,z]=[n[0],n[1],n[2]]
    n= [z,y,x]
    n= n.join("")
    n= parseInt(n)
  return n
}


console.log([a,switchIt(b)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple ajust and your code will work as expected:

```
arr.some((x,i)=>{
    var end = i >= (arr.length - 1);
    a=arr[i]
    if (!end) {
        b=arr[i+1]
        b = switchIt(b)
    }
    if(a!==b || end){ //note the OR with end variable here
       a = -1
       b = -1
    }else{
       return a==b
    }      
})
```

The ajust consists in test when some function find the end of array

Answer (score 9):

> Given an array of numbers, I wish to use javascript's .some() method to find the first pair of mirror image numbers and return the pair.

That's not what `some` does. `some` returns a boolean: Either the predicate function returned a truthy value (so `some` returns `true`), or it never returned a truthy value (so `some` returns `false`).

Although you *can* use `some` for what you want, what you really want is `find` (added in ES2015, but fully shimmable/polyfillable). Here's a simpler example:

```js
var a = [
  {id: 1, value: "one"},
  {id: 2, value: "two"},
  {id: 3, value: "three"},
  {id: 4, value: "four"},
  {id: 5, value: "five"}
];
var entry = a.find(function(e) {
  return e.id === 3;
});
console.log(entry);
```

---

Just for completeness, you *can* do taht with `find`, by using a variable the `some` predicate closes over:

```js
var a = [
  {id: 1, value: "one"},
  {id: 2, value: "two"},
  {id: 3, value: "three"},
  {id: 4, value: "four"},
  {id: 5, value: "five"}
];
var entry;
a.some(function(e) {
  if (e.id === 3) {
    entry = e;
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(entry);
```

...but I don't recommend that. This is exactly what `find` was designed for.

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about find(). Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.some` returns a boolean, `true` if the callback function returns a truthy value for any array element; otherwise, `false`.

If you want to return the value, you could use `reduce` instead, but it will iterate to the end

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(a,b,i) {
    if (a[0]!==-1) return a;
    if ( (""+b).split("").reverse().join("") == arr[i+1] ) return [b, arr[i+1]];
    return a;
},[-1,-1]);
```

Comment: I always have this confusion of using `.split().reverse().join()`  or use custom reverse function. I still don't know which would be better.

Comment: It won't find mirrors that don't have consecutive indexes.

Comment: @OriDrori - I assumed that was the point, as they are next to each other in the given example

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using `array.some` for this case. Purpose of `.some` is to check if a condition is satisfied or not. If you wish to fetch values, you should use other functions. I'd suggest `array.reduce`

```js
function getMirrorPair(arr) {
  var retArr = [-1, -1]
  try {
    arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
      if (c === getReverse(p)) {
        retArr[0] = p;
        retArr[1] = c;
        throw new Error()
      }
      return c
    })
  } catch (ex) {}
  return retArr
}

function getReverse(num) {
  var tmp = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
    tmp = (tmp || 0) * 10 + (num % 10);
    num = parseInt(num / 10);
  }
  return tmp
}
var arr = [13, 15, 23, 32, 49, 61, 73];
var arr1 = [13, 15, 19, 32, 49, 61, 73];
var r = getMirrorPair(arr);
var r1 = getMirrorPair(arr1);
console.log(r)
console.log(r1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. For some reason this assignment was presented as part of learning the .some() method, so your recommendation is good to know.